# Saved png image lose transparency when inserted in Catia V5 CATDrawing

Tags: c#, png, catia

I have a problem with transparency in the .png image when inserting to Catia V5 CATDrawing document. Something changes in the image after saving with `System.Drawing.Image.Save()`. If a newly saved image is opened with Paint.NET image is transparent and everything seems fine, but when inserted in CATDrawing image has no transparency. I can't find out what is changed in the image to cause this loss of transparency.
I'm rotating image that's why I need to save it. This is the code I'm using to rotate and save images.

```
    Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(sImagePath1, true);
    image1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    image1.MakeTransparent();
    image1.Save(sImagePath2, ImageFormat.Png);
```

I have also tried and failed with NuGet package Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU

```
    using (MagickImage mimg = new(sImagePath1))
    {
        mimg.Rotate(90);
        mimg.Write(sImagePath2);
    }
```

and with save as stream

```
    Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(sImagePath1, true);
    image1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    using (FileStream outputFileStream = new(sImagePath2, FileMode.Create))
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        image1.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.CopyTo(outputFileStream);
    }
```

Question: is there any other solution to rotate and save images via C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm afraid that Catia V5 can't import png with transparency. Try it yourself if manually putting the image into drawing keeps transparency. I Tried it but in my case it doesn't work.

In Catia you can rotate the picture manually but not trough api.

You can try vector image instead of bitmap, but this is just my guess.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, yes you can import png with transparency in CATDrawing. If you save a picture for example with Paint.NET and insert it in CATDrawing. When I rotate and save the picture with code something changes and the picture loses transparancy.